# What is the proper way(design pattern) to manage windows across WPF application using MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls

I am writing a budget managing app using WPF and MVVM architecture. It has a lot of windows which can be opened by button clicks (create transaction, create account) etc, however I am not sure how to manage them across the whole application.
For example, I do not want to allow the user to open another "create transaction" window, unless the previous one is closed. The user should not be able to open many identical windows, so if he clicks on the button again, while the previous window is not closed, it should not work.
I have in mind creating a static class which will have a list of opened windows names, so every time the viewmodel will check the list whether the window of some type is already opened.(I open windows from ViewModel) However maybe there is some better approach or design pattern for this, thanks!

P.S. I do not use any frameworks for MVVM and do not plan to.

Example:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vssX1.jpg

Comment: For your windows, just pre-instantiate them, put them in a Dictionary and only call Show(). If you don't want to instantiate them, try to bind them an id, or look if Window object is not in dictionary. You could use a pattern for that, but that'd be overcomplicating the thing. If you insist, there's Singleton, FlyWeight that might interest you.

Comment: If you open a create new account window for example isnt it modal by default ? I mean you shouldnt be able to click anything in the parent window until you you child window.

Comment: @VladyslavBabych, could you please post the client pseudo-code to demonstrate what would you like to achieve?